# At the login of SAM2 itself can claims attributes be saved?

Tags: saml-2.0

Checking all the available libraries, we decided to use ItFortec SAML library. The login happens without any issues, but it redirects to destination page. Before it redirects is there a way to capture the SAML response and store claims attributes in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free tools like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), or use Saml Tracer for Chrome browser (extension). Both have numerous tutorials how to capture the full trace of the saml flow between IDP and SP. Hope this gets you started, if not post your question.